# Solid with Boiling Point less than 100 °C

Tags: water, solubility, boiling-point

For an experiment I require a substance which is a solid at room temperature and boils at a temperature lower than 100 °C. Also, this solid should preferably be soluble in water. Are there any such compounds?

Comment: If you're going to edit your question in response to an answer, you should make it clear how you've changed it.  If you don't, then you can make an answer look bad, as you have to mine.  That is at best careless, at worst unethical.

Comment: My bad check edits

Answer (score 3):

[Ammonium bicarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_bicarbonate) seems like a winner.  It:

1. Is a solid at RTP.
2. Is highly soluble in water.  At RTP, the solubility is about 3 moles of $\ce{NH4HCO3}$ per liter.
3. Decomposes at high temperatures to a gas.  Well, actually, two gases: $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{NH3}$.

This decomposition is not truly "boiling", but it does involve a transformation into gases.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a melting point, and by 'turns into a gas' you haven't specified boiling.

Iodine sublimes readily and is also sparingly soluble in water.

If you really mean 'solid at RTP, boils below 100 and readily soluble in water' then clearly Iodine doesn't meet that more stringent requirement.

Comment: You could add iodide to the water.